# How to Insert or Update in a Many to Many relationship EF?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am struggling with inserting or updating records in a many to many relationship.The problem is with the cross-table.I have generated the classes with Entity Framework Database First.Even if i clear the cross table and i repopulate it i get unique constraint exception.How should i proceed?

**Structure:**

(**Story**) 1------N  (**StoryLocation**) N-------1 (**Location**)

**Generated tables and context**

```
public partial class Story
{
    public Story()
    {
        StoryLocation = new HashSet<StoryLocation>();
    }

    [Column("id", TypeName = "bigint(20)")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Story")]
    public ICollection<StoryLocation> StoryLocation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        StoryLocation = new HashSet<StoryLocation>();
    }

    [Column("id", TypeName = "bigint(20)")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Location")]
    public ICollection<StoryLocation> StoryLocation { get; set; }
}



public partial class StoryLocation
    {
        [Column("story_id", TypeName = "bigint(20)")]
        public long StoryId { get; set; }
        [Column("location_id", TypeName = "bigint(20)")]
        public long LocationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
        [InverseProperty("StoryLocation")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StoryId")]
        [InverseProperty("StoryLocation")]
        public Story Story { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext** and **Fluent Api:**

```
public partial class TreasureContext : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StoryLocation> StoryLocations { get; set; }

    public TreasureContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server[servername];Port=3306;
                        Database[dbname];Uid=[admin];Pwd=[pwd];");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ActivityId)
                .HasName("FKh3ry7cjb7l4vv0qx8d2jbcrcx");
        });



     modelBuilder.Entity<StoryLocation>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LocationId, e.StoryId });

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.StoryId)
                .HasName("FK_story");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Location)
                .WithMany(p => p.StoryLocation)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.LocationId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_location");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Story)
                .WithMany(p => p.StoryLocation)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StoryId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_story");
        });

    }
}
```

ASP MVC Action and wrapper argument:

```
public class Relation
{
    public long storyid{get;set;}
    public List<Location>locations;
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Attach")]
public IActionResult Attach([FromBody]Relation relation)
{
    Story targetStory=this.context.Stories.Find(relation.storyid);
    if(targetStory!=null)
    {
        this.context.StoryLocations.RemoveRange(
            from slocation in this.context.StoryLocations 
            where slocation.StoryId.Equals(targetStory.Id)
            select slocation
            );

        foreach(Location loc in relation.locations)
        {
            this.context.StoryLocations.Add(new 
            StoryLocation{Location=loc,Story=targetStory});
        }
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Story");
}
```

I want to attach all Locations received in the ASP MVC Action argument to the story with the storyid also in the argument.

Comment: The problem is `relation.locations` is untracked so EF will try to add them again. You could set the entity state to no changes, but since you have LocationId exposed just use that:`this.context.StoryLocations.Add(new StoryLocation {LocationId=loc.Id, StoryId=targetStory.Id});`

Comment: So far i have tried to add new StoryLocations with only the ID's(as you pointed out) ,with the concrete objects(story and location),with both the objects and the id's and i get the following error:      '
 Innermost exception   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'  . This error appears even at first run when my tables are empty !!

Comment: You may have to set the Story and Location to null when doing a FK update (not sure). Otherwise, tell EF the location is not a new one: `context.Entry(loc).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`. Since targetStory was fetched from the context you do not need to do it for that item.

Comment: After i started tracking the location and Attach() it  if it was detached the records get saved.However the problem with duplicates persists.What would be a good method to guard against inserting duplicates in the cross-table?

Comment: The cross table primary key is LocationId + StoryId, so that should not happen. Do you mean you are getting 2 locations (or stories) that are duplicates with different keys? That can happen if the state was not set properly.

Comment: No now the insertion works fine.But i don't know if i must use the EntityState again when deleting.

Comment: You can avoid entity state stuff altogether if you fetch the items into the context before updating or deleting. So to delete: `var storyLocationToDel = context.StoryLocations.Single(s => s.LocationID == locId && s.StoryId == storyId);` then `context.StoryLocation.Remove(storyLocationToDel);` then `context.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: So a valid approach for my Attach method would be first to Single() and Remove() every StoryLocation present in the database for the given storyid and then Add() new StoryLocations in the  context table.All this done before a SaveChanges() call.

Comment: You can still use removerange. The point is to either use the context to track the items, or set the entity states appropriately.

Comment: In the RemoveRange() description it says it will start to track the entities to be removed and remove them when the SaveChanges() occurs.I need somehow to guarantee that the RemoveRange is the first operation that will be executed on the concrete database (after the SaveChanges() call) .Otherwise i have to perform 1.RemoveRange(all elements for storyID) 2.SaveChanges() 3.Add new elements 4.SaveChanges()

Comment: You can [log the generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) to verify.